# how to hook Registry newly created

Tags: c++, registry, api-hook

I know how to hook API. but I don't know what API is called when Registry is newly created.

I want to detect Registry Create Time and I want to know that Key, Data.
Is there any API available for hooking related to registry ?
And How to know that API is best?

Comment: Don't hook. [RegNotifyChangeKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx).

Comment: @theB my question was strange. I want to prevent registration in accordance with the Key, Data... I think RegNotifyChangeKey can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that.

Through msdn and procmon.exe, ZwCreateKey is called when create registry.
so i hook this API. And get Data!

but still I don't know exactly correct about ZwCreateKey is best.